# How to efficiently collapse a vector of integers into a data.table of sequences, using R?

Tags: r, performance, data.table, sequence

Given a large vector. For example:

```
set.seed(1)
in_vec <- sample(1:10000, 5000, replace = F)
```

How can I efficiently collapse this into a datatable that provides the start and end coordinates for all sequential integers. I am currently using the following code:

```
in_vec <- sort(in_vec) # sort by sequence
library(data.table)
interval_id <- findInterval(in_vec, in_vec[which(c(1, diff(in_vec)) > 1)]) # add unique IDs for sequences
dt <- data.table(vec = in_vec, # make data.table
             int_id = interval_id)
long_to_short <- function(sub){ data.table(start = sub$vec[1], end = sub$vec[nrow(sub)]) } # custom function
library(plyr)
output <- ddply(dt, "int_id", long_to_short)
output$int_id <- NULL
```

However, the vector I am applying this to is very large, and I therefore need to maximise performance. Is there a data.table method? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you show first few values of expected output ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `rleid()` from [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) is helpful:

```
library(data.table)

set.seed(1)
dt <- data.table(in_vec = sample(1:10000, 5000, replace = F)) 

dt[order(in_vec), 
   .(start = min(in_vec),
     end = max(in_vec)),
   by = .(grp = rleid(c(0, cumsum(diff(in_vec) > 1))))
   ]

       grp start  end
   1:    1     4    4
   2:    2     6    7
   3:    3    14   16
   4:    4    19   19
   5:    5    26   27
  ---                
2483: 2483  9980 9980
2484: 2484  9988 9988
2485: 2485  9991 9992
2486: 2486  9994 9994
2487: 2487  9997 9998
```

For a completely base solution, this should be the most performant as it is not a grouping operation:

```
set.seed(1)
in_vec <- sample(1:10000, 5000, replace = F)
in_vec <- sort(in_vec)

grp <- c(0, cumsum(diff(in_vec) > 1))

data.frame(grp = unique(grp),
           start = in_vec[!duplicated(grp)],
           end = in_vec[!duplicated(grp, fromLast = T)]
)
```

Comment: wow, never knew this function exist. Gone are the days of coding in base R...

Comment: @StupidWolf, after reviewing, ```rleid()``` wasn't necessary. But the function is helpful for other problems. I already +1 yours for your base solution. Long live base :)

Comment: @StupidWolf, sorry to bug you, see edit for a completely base approach. Again, long live base.

Comment: Good solution! Yeah that's the fastest

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
dt[, .(start = first(vec), end = last(vec)), int_id]
```

Edit:  I think the following will do what you need within data.table, adjust the `fill = -1` depending on the actual range of your values.

```
set.seed(1)
in_vec <- sample(1:10000, 5000, replace = F)
dt <- data.table(vec = in_vec, key = 'vec')
dt[, int_id := cumsum(!shift(vec, 1, fill = -1) == vec - 1)]
dt[,.(start = first(vec), end = last(vec)), int_id]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there, just need to use the difference between sorted vectors to create a group. Then do range on them.

```
set.seed(1)
in_vec <- sample(1:10000, 5000, replace = F)
in_vec <- sort(in_vec)
grps <- cumsum(c(1,diff(in_vec)>1))

output <- data.frame(do.call(rbind,tapply(in_vec,grps,range)))
names(output) <- c("start","end")
```

And a dplyr solution

```
set.seed(1)
in_vec <- sample(1:10000, 5000, replace = F)
data.frame(x=in_vec) %>% 
arrange(x) %>%
mutate(grps=cumsum(c(1,diff(x)>1))) %>%
group_by(grps) %>%
summarise(start=min(x),end=max(x)) %>%
select(start,end)
```